# Want to load same name file from Folder nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, winginx

I am new to nginx server. I want to load same name file from folder. Suppose:

I have file system as:

```
folder/xyz/xyz.html
```

I am want to access xyz.html file using this url: http://localhost:84/xyz using nginx server. I have created the configuration like as:

```
server {
    rewrite_log on;
    listen :84;
    server_name localhost;      

    root folder;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html /index.html;
    }
}
```

With this configuration I am successfully accessible the folder/xyz/index.html file. But I want to access folder/xyz/xyz.html file.

NOTE: name ("xyz") will be dynamically.

Can any please help me.

Comment: Have you tried `$uri$uri.html` in your `try_files` statement?